# celery workers not releasing memory after tasks are finished

Tags: python, linux, celery

I am running celery with redis as the broker, on centos 6.5 machine, with the following configuration:

```
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_ENABLE_UTC=True,
    CELERY_SEND_TASK_SENT_EVENT=True,
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['msgpack', 'json', 'application/x-python-serialize'],
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='msgpack',
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER='msgpack',
    CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER=1)
```

The problem is, even when there are no tasks in the queue, and no active tasks at all, the memory is not released

Any idea might help!

Answer (score 2):

Usually, Unix processes do not systematically return to the OS the memory they acquire from it when they no longer need it. So over time the memory usage of a process will increase.

If you are satisfied there's no actual coding or configuration problem affecting your workers, you could restart them periodically.

Answer (score 2):

You need CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD for your celery settings, please see:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/configuration.html#celeryd-max-tasks-per-child